# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm tryin to create a multi-class multi-label confusion matrix. I started out by making a simple code to test the waters which is working perfectly!

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


y_true = np.array([[0,0,1], [1,1,0],[0,1,0], [0,0,1]])
y_pred = np.array([[3.11640739e-01, 7.03224633e-03, 5.24131523e-04], [1,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]])

labels = ["A", "B", "C"]

conf_mat_dict={}

for label_col in range(len(labels)):
    y_true_label = y_true[:, label_col]
    y_pred_label = y_pred[:, label_col].astype(int)
    print(len(y_pred_label))
    print(y_pred_label)
    conf_mat_dict[labels[label_col]] = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_label, y_true=y_true_label)


for label, matrix in conf_mat_dict.items():
    print("Confusion matrix for label {}:".format(label))
    print(matrix)
```

Now I am trying to implement this code into my classifier. But I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module/xvisionkeras.py", line 137, in <module>
    conf_mat_dict[all_labels[label_col]] = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_label, y_true=y_true_label)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 253, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 81, in _check_targets
    "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets
```

This is what my y_true and y_pred look like from my classifier:

```
y_true = [[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]]
y_pred = [[3.11640739e-01 7.03224633e-03 5.24131523e-04 3.86616620e-07
  1.76620641e-04 2.04237878e-07 1.33097637e-02 9.73195732e-02
  4.40102362e-04 1.43901054e-02 1.97768782e-06 3.82719515e-03
  1.00047495e-02 2.02647328e-07]
 [9.50563997e-02 3.03714332e-04 2.36625488e-06 9.52693328e-13
  7.04080634e-08 2.23670063e-12 4.18162963e-04 8.28180760e-02
  3.15815419e-06 7.02972582e-04 8.19261742e-11 1.01527738e-04
  7.73170555e-04 1.85218228e-13]
 [2.22699329e-01 2.33753794e-03 9.19468803e-05 7.17655990e-10
  3.76326443e-06 2.58434874e-09 3.70667153e-03 1.12193748e-01
  1.60316195e-04 3.16509278e-03 1.77856236e-08 7.23963138e-04
  5.58568537e-03 3.64327679e-10]
 [2.01257914e-01 2.55549047e-03 8.14868326e-05 8.32152924e-09
  2.27710298e-05 5.02339681e-09 6.01076195e-03 6.39715046e-02
  4.62430944e-05 8.06804933e-03 8.95162486e-08 1.28999283e-03
  2.87817954e-03 2.70706768e-09]
 [1.99281245e-01 5.05847216e-04 4.23961183e-06 6.71859304e-11
  8.09664698e-07 4.37779007e-10 1.80601899e-03 2.89123088e-01
  6.22663310e-06 9.77680553e-04 3.53975094e-09 2.74123857e-04
  3.29167116e-03 3.53774961e-11]]
```

Could someone point out to me what I am doing wrong? I have been stuck on this problem for ages!

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ added it :-)

Comment: You cannot use confusion matrix for regressions. It can be used only for classification, when both true and predicted values are boolean or categorical.

Comment: how many classes do you have in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to compare integer and non-integer values.
`(1 == 0.99)` would never match until you round the non integer value.

```
y_true, y_pred = [0, 1], [0.7, 0.3]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
>> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Rounding `y_pred` would make the job.
But, I don't think `scikit-learn` supports multiclass-multilabel confusion matrices.
You will get a

```
>> ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

You can however compute other metrics, such as `accuracy score` (the higher the better) or the `hamming loss` (the lower the better)

```
y_true = np.random.choice(2, (5, 14), p=[0.7, 0.3])
y_pred_round = np.random.choice(2, (5, 14), p=[0.7, 0.3])
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, hamming_loss

# Accuracy Score
accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred_round, normalize=True, sample_weight=None)
((y_pred_round == y_true).all(axis=1).sum() / y_pred_round.shape[0])

# Hamming Loss
hamming_loss(y_true, y_pred_round)
scores = (y_pred_round != y_true).sum(axis=1)
numerator = scores.sum()
denominator = ((scores != 0).sum() * y_true.shape[1])
hl = (numerator / denominator)
```

What else can you do with `(y_pred_round != y_true)` or `(y_pred_round == y_true)` ? Summing them (`.sum(axis=1)` and `.sum(axis=0)`), rearange, divide, define other metrics